# Dynamically creating an ssh tunnel from docker server to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I've not used ssh tunnels before, so this might be easy to resolve for someone who is experienced.
My ultimate goal is to dynamically create a tunnel in php, then use pdo's mysql driver to run SQL commands on the remote MySQL server.
After a few days of failure there, I'm trying to go back to basics and just get anything running over a tunnel with minimal other rules or software getting in the way.
My question is, "What am I doing wrong".  I would think this should be simple:

- create a tunnel from localhost:1234 to remotehost:22
- ssh to local port 1234 should connect to ssh on the remotehost.

`ssh $SSHUSER@$SSHSERVER`
- This works just fine.  I get a shell on the remote server

iptables on the mysql server has no rules and does not exist on the php server.  hosts.allow and hosts.deny are empty on both servers.

I've tried various ports, I've tried it with mysql & port 3306, I even tried "nc -l -p 1234" and created a tunnel to that port.  MySQL Workbench is able to connect over an ssh tunnel from my workstation (Workbench took care of tunnels, not me) so I know it is possible.

## Server 1:  the PHP Server

```
## This is a docker image running on my workstation.
```

```
        cat /etc/os-release 
            PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
            NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
            VERSION_ID="11"
            VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
            VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
            ID=debian
            HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
            SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
            BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
        php -r 'echo phpversion()."\n";'
            8.1.8
        php -r 'echo phpversion("ssh2")."\n";'
            1.4
        php -r 'echo phpversion("PDO_MYSQL")."\n";'
            8.1.8
        mysql --version
            mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.19-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
        ssh -V
            OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
        nc -q 1 $MYSQLSERVER 22
            SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6
            ^C
```

## Server 2:  The MySQL server.

```
## This is a cloud server running wordpress
```

```
        cat /etc/os-release 
            NAME="Ubuntu"
            VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
            ID=ubuntu
            ID_LIKE=debian
            PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
            VERSION_ID="18.04"
            HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
            SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
            BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
            PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
            VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
            UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

```
        grep -R bind /etc/mysql/
            bind-address         = 0.0.0.0
```

```
        mysql --version
            mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.42, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

```
    netstat -tulpn | grep mysql
            tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18923/mysqld
```

```
        netstat -tulpn | grep ssh
            tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      877/sshd            
            tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      877/sshd
```

```
        ssh -V
            OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

```
        mysql -u $MYSQLUSER -h 127.0.0.1 -p
            This works
```

```
        mysql -u $MYSQLUSER -h localhost -p
            This works
```

## My testing script:

```
    PHPSERVERPORT="1234"
    MYSQLSERVERPORT="22"        # 22 for testing, ultimate goal is 3306
    SSHLOG="/tmp/sshdebug.log"
    TESTLOG="/tmp/test.log"
    VERBOSE="-v"
    SSHUSER="someone"
    SSHSERVER=$MYSQLSERVER
    MYSQLUSER="someoneelse"


    PHPSERVER="127.0.0.1"       # localhost is another option
    MYSQLSERVER="20.xx.xx.7"

    # "ssh -v -p $PHPSERVERPORT $SSHUSER@$SSHSERVER > $TESTLOG 2>&1"
    # "mysql -h $PHPSERVER -u $MYSQLUSER -p > $TESTLOG 2>&1"
    TUNNELTEST="ssh -v -p $PHPSERVERPORT $SSHUSER@$SSHSERVER > $TESTLOG 2>&1"  


    # Create a tunnel
    echo "-----------------------------Tunnel creation---------------------------"
    ssh -f -N -L $PHPSERVER:$PHPSERVERPORT:$MYSQLSERVER:$MYSQLSERVERPORT $SSHUSER@$SSHSERVER $VERBOSE > $SSHLOG 2>&1
    sleep 10  # Give it time to create the connection
    cat $SSHLOG

    # Test the tunnel
    echo "-----------------------------Tunnel test ---------------------------"
    $TUNNELTEST
    cat $TESTLOG

    # Tear down the tunnel
    echo "-----------------------------Tunnel removal ---------------------------"
    TunnelID=$(ps aux | grep "ssh -f -N -L $PHPSERVER:$PHPSERVERPORT" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    kill $TunnelID
    echo "----------------------------- tail ssh log ---------------------------"
    tail -6 $SSHLOG
    rm $SSHLOG
    rm $TESTLOG
```

## Output from testing script:

```
    -----------------------------Tunnel creation---------------------------
    OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to 20.xx.xx.7 [20.xx.xx.7] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
    debug1: Authenticating to 20.xx.xx.7:22 as '$SSHUSER'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ck5uSnszi/bEtk+G5r2P6odA+kB6YA//V7YgvhvZIV0
    debug1: Host '20.xx.xx.7' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Aashj6v3d2CRANWOCoui99BJsifd/QTm5AxFB1ijXNQ
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Aashj6v3d2CRANWOCoui99BJsifd/QTm5AxFB1ijXNQ
    debug1: Server accepts key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Aashj6v3d2CRANWOCoui99BJsifd/QTm5AxFB1ijXNQ
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
    Authenticated to 20.xx.xx.7 ([20.xx.xx.7]:22).
    debug1: Local connections to 127.0.0.1:1234 forwarded to remote address 20.xx.xx.7:22
    debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1234.
    debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: forking to background
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: network
    debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
    -----------------------------Tunnel test ---------------------------
    OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to 20.xx.xx.7 [20.xx.xx.7] port 1234.
    debug1: connect to address 20.xx.xx.7 port 1234: Connection refused
    ssh: connect to host 20.xx.xx.7 port 1234: Connection refused
    cat: /tmp/test.log: No such file or directory
    -----------------------------Tunnel removal ---------------------------
    ----------------------------- tail ssh log ---------------------------
    debug1: pledge: network
    debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
    debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 1
    Transferred: sent 3120, received 2520 bytes, in 31.1 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 100.5, received 81.1
    debug1: Exit status 0
    rm: cannot remove '/tmp/test.log': No such file or directory
```

## Observations:

### During the tunnel test

```
    OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
        same as "ssh -V" on the php server
    ...
    debug1: Connecting to 20.xx.xx.7 [20.xx.xx.7] port 1234.
    debug1: connect to address 20.xx.xx.7 port 1234: Connection refused
    ssh: connect to host 20.xx.xx.7 port 1234: Connection refused
        These lines are what confuses me
        I am connecting to local port 1234, which should be remote port 22
```

Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: This seems a little complicated.  Usually speaking your database server will be "non public facing" so it can't be reached from the outside -- With that said it's safe and faster just to use a MySQL call via MySQL port (whether that be, 3306 for example).  Else if the remote server is NOT in your network, building an API in PHP with OAUTH that connects directly to the database and output the result to your "getter" would be a better solution.  Tunnelling and THEN using MySQL seem more convoluted than needs be.